# Standard Logic App - Extract Archive to Folder

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a Consumption Logic App where we Create a .zip blob in a storage account and then extract its content into the same storage, as follows:

[image]

We created a Standard Logic App to replace the Consumption one, but the Extract archive to folder (V2) fails with "**400 Bad Request**  Unable to extract contents of file xxxx"
All other Create blob (V2) activities work fine.

The connection and the parameters are the same in both Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and expected results as below:

I have first faced same error as you(Created Standard Logic app) :

[image]

Then changed **overwrite** to `Yes`, It worked :

[image]

Succeeded Output:

[image]

File Extracted in Blob Storage:

[image]

Code view :

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@variables('emo')",
                    "headers": {
                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "azureblob"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/rithwik",
                        "name": "emo.txt",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Extract_archive_to_folder_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "azureblob"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/extractFolderV2",
                    "queries": {
                        "destination": "/rithwik",
                        "overwrite": true,
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true,
                        "source": "/rithwik/emo1.zip"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_blob_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "emo ra babu"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```